# should be (have been) called

Tags: grammar

Which of these is better: `this function should be called` or `this function should have been called`?

The event `function is called` has occurred. We are now in the past.

Comment: Are you talking about naming the function, or executing the function?

Comment: Neither is better or worse than the other because they have different meanings.

Comment: If the event has occurred, it's easily "should have been". "Should be called" would be correct as a directive not a statement for a past event.

Comment: @PeterShor we are talking about execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're asking whether you should use past or present tense?

Since the function should have been called prior to the event having occurred, past tense is proper here.

`TheFunction() should have been called prior to calling TheOtherFunction()`

However, if calling the first function prior to the second is a required task, you may want to use "must" instead of "should":

`TheFunction() must have been called prior to calling TheOtherFunction()`